How to import hector slam data on python code
We have a robot controlled by arduino that we planing to get mapping data from raspberry pi connected to lidar. I researched a lot about reading data from hector slam by using Python. I only find one about arduino but it didn't help. My question is: Can We extract data to Python code;if so how (Can you provide sources you know), if not what can we try else?
